# Calling a React side-effect inside a onClick method. Is there a a better implementation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I have a Navigation Panel with [link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) to different pages inside the react app. I want to highlight the currently navigation link. I am able to achieve this by adding a class to active nav link. My implementation is as below:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Nav() {

    const highlight = (e) => {
        // Remove .nav-select class from all nav items
        let eles = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-select");
        eles.forEach.call(eles, (ele) => {
            ele.classList.remove('nav-select');
        })
        // Add .nav-select to currently clicked nav item
        e.target.className = e.target.className + " nav-select"
    }

    return (
        <nav className="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li onClick={highlight}>
                    <Link to="/" >Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li onClick={highlight}>
                    <Link to="/blog" >Blog</Link>
                </li>
                <li onClick={highlight}>
                    <Link to="/clock" >Clock</Link>
                </li>
                <li onClick={highlight}>
                    <Link to="/video" >Video</Link>
                </li>
                <li onClick={highlight}>
                    <Link to="/goals" >Goals</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Nav;
```

Related styling:

```
.main-nav .nav-select {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px
}
```

This is giving me the expected result.

As per my understanding, a call to document and it's modification is a side-effect, and it is good practice to handle side-effects inside `useEffect()` hook. Is it just a good practice or is it a rule that might lead to issues if not followed?
Is there a better implementation or a way to improve my implementaion, to achieve my expected result?

Comment: There’s a component that does exactly what you’re trying to do manually called NavLink in react-router, is that where Link is coming from? Also, if you’re manipulating the DOM with react, you’re doing it wrong

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll`,  In React this it's very rarely the way to do anything with the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, using `<NavLink>` is the recommended way but the root problem you're having is not thinking "the React way". This means you should avoid direct manipulation of the DOM, such as `document.querySelectorAll` and directly modifying DOM elements to add/remove classes and such.

The react way is to store state and have the DOM render according to this state. When you want to change something on an element, update your state and the DOM will be re-rendered to reflect the changes.

For example, without using `<NavLink>`, you could solve the problem like so:

**[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-pp7dod)**

```
const App = () => {
  const [links, setLinks] = useState([
    { text: "Home", to: "/", active: false },
    { text: "About", to: "/about", active: false },
    { text: "Topics", to: "/topics", active: false }
  ]);

  const handleClick = (clickedLink) => {
    setLinks(links.map((link) => ({ ...link, active: clickedLink === link })));
  };

  return (
    <Router>
        <ul>
          {links.map((link, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <Link
                onClick={() => handleClick(link)}
                className={link.active ? "nav-active" : ""}
                to={link.to}
              >
                {link.text}
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

This works by storing an array of objects which represent the link in state, and to render these using `.map()`. There is a click event which passes the clicked link and then updates the state to set the `active` property to `true` for the clicked link and `false` for all others. When the link is rendered this `active` property is used to set the `nav-active` class or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#navlink) instead of `Link`, and use the `isActive` prop to control the class:

```
<li>
  <NavLink to="/" 
    style={({ isActive }) => 
      className={({ isActive }) =>
        isActive ? 'nav-select' : undefined
      } 
    }>Home
  </NavLink>
</li>
```

Comment: Setting style > className is giving me Syntax error, but a modified approach of setting className directly is working as expected. 
`                <li>
                    <NavLink to="/" className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'nav-select' : undefined}>Home</NavLink>
                </li>`

Comment: The answer sets up the `className`. It's based on the 2nd example in the link. With the style option you need to set the actual value.